# pthread_cancel() function failed to terminate a thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm using `pthread_create()` and `pthread_cancel()` functions to create a multithreaded program, but I noticed that `pthread_cancel()` did not really terminate the thread it was supposed to.

```
void check(void *param){
    header_t *Bag = (header_t *) param;
    pthread_t timer_thread;
    while(true){
        if(Bag->size && TIMER_OFF){
            pthread_create(&timer_thread, NULL, (void *) &timer, (void *) Bag);
            printf("\nCREATE THREAD ID = %d\n", timer_thread);
            // ADD
        }
        else if(!TIMER_OFF && Bag->size >= 2 && Bag->next->time <= CURRENT_APT_TIME && CRRENT_TAG != Bag->next->tag){
            printf("\nOLD THREAD ID = %d TO BE CANCELLED\n", timer_thread);
            pthread_cancel(timer_thread);
            pthread_create(&timer_thread, NULL, (void *) &timer, (void *) Bag);
            printf("\nNEW THREAD ID = %d\n", timer_thread);
            // Replace
        }
        Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

timer function `void timer(void *)` is exactly what it sounds like, and I've included couple of lines to print out the thread ID of itself.

When tested, the following was seen:

```
...

OLD THREAD ID = 6041240 TO BE CANCELLED

NEW THREAD ID = 6046456

...

THREAD ID EXECUTING = 6041240
```

So the timer function was not terminated by calling `pthread_cancel()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default your thread is created with the [cancel type](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_setcanceltype) `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED`, which means that you need to make sure that your thread has a so-called **cancellation point**. That is, a point where cancel requests are checked and reacted upon.

[This page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) contains a list of functions that are guaranteed to be cancellation points. Examples are some of the `sleep()` and pthread functions. You can also use `pthread_testcancel()` if you just need a function to purely test whether the thread has been canceled, and nothing else.

Another option is to set your threads canceltype to be `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS`, by using `pthread_setcanceltype()`, which will make your thread cancelable even without cancellation points. However, the system is still free to choose when the thread should actually be canceled, and you'll need to take great care to make sure that the system isn't left in an inconsistent state when cancelled (typically means avoiding any system calls and similar - see the list of [Async-cancel-safe functions](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) - it's short!).

In general, asynchronous cancellation should only be used for more or less "pure" processing threads, whereas threads performing system calls and similar are better implemented with deferred cancellation and careful placement of cancellation points.

Also, as long as you are not [detaching your thread](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html) (by either creating it detached through its attribute, or by calling `pthread_detach()` after it is created), you will need to call `pthread_join()` on the timer thread to make sure that all resources are cleaned up after canceling it. Otherwise you might end up in a state without any spare threading resources, where you cannot create any new threads.

Answer (score 0):

The default cancel method of `pthread_cancel()` is delayed cancel.So when you invoke `pthread_cancel()`, it will not really cancel before the specified thread reach the cancel point.You shoud call `pthread_setcanceltype` to set another cancel method to your thread.