# pthread_cancel not working

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, pthreads

I have where 2 pthreads namely t1 and t2 are created in the main and joined. Their handlers go to function a and b respectively given below.

```
void a()
{
 .....
 usleep(1000000);
 pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
 .....
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
}
void b()
{
 .....
 usleep(1000000);
 pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
 .....
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
}
```

when i call pthread_cancel(t1) during the sleep time, the cancel is unsuccessful and it returns a value 3. How to cancel this thread or How to force kill a thread with its name say t1 or t2 from main?

Comment: sharing the part of code which creates and cancels thread can be helpful

Comment: Need to change the thread's cancel type from deferred (default) to asynchronous: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271616/pthread-cancel-function-failed-to-terminate-a-thread/

Comment: If you see yourself confronted with the need to forcefully terminate a thread ("*kill it*") you mainly are facing a desgin issue, to not call it "flaw".

Comment: usleep() is not a cancellation point as of POSIX.1-2008 http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html

Comment: OT: A pthread function's signature ought to be `void * f(void*)`.

Comment: From the current question it's not quite possible to see what the problem actually is - either post a minimal, complete and verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or try having a look at how cancellation works - for instance, have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11272514/1282949

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the syntax for [`pthread_cancel()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cancel) function

```
int pthread_cancel(pthread_t thread);
```

So, you should be calling `pthread_cancel(t1);` , IMO.

Also, try enabling *cancelability state* of the thread functions using the `pthread_setcancelstate()` API with a value of `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE` and change the *cancellation type* to asynchronous using  `pthread_setcanceltype()`.

Note: The [link to this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11271616/2173917) by **@amdn** may be helpful, too.

Comment: I am sorry. .Its just t1..

Comment: Wouldnt pthread_setcancelstate() set the state for all the pthreads in the program.

Comment: @Punkster Yes, I think so.

Comment: @Punkster: No. From the relevant man-page: "*The  `pthread_setcancelstate()`  sets the cancelability state of the calling thread to the value given in state.*"

Comment: @alk You're very right sir. I guess its choice of poor wordings by me. What I meant is like if you use the `pthread_setcancelstate()` in the thread functions (unconditionally), then all the threads with that thread function will be set to that state only.

Comment: Can u give an example code for the same?

Comment: Be VERY careful when using asynchronous cancellation, as it may lead to an inconsistent system state if you try cancelling the thread when it is in a system call or similar - see my answer here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271616/pthread-cancel-function-failed-to-terminate-a-thread/11272514?s=9|4.3677#11272514

Comment: @sonicwave You're very right. I havd already added a link to your answer [to be precise, to the actual question]. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a `SIGKILL` signal using `pthread_kill(tid, SIGKILL)`.

Comment: This would bring down the whole process, including all its threads.